# What happens when I delete my Facebook

Tags: facebook

When I delete my Facebook do my likes stay on the things I like? For example on one of my friends pictures I liked will it say 10 likes but when I view the people only 9 people will be listed my name won't be? Or will the picture actually say 9 likes and list 9 people?

Answer (score 1):

When you [delete your account](https://www.facebook.com/help/224562897555674), people won't be able to see it on Facebook. It may take up to 90 days from the beginning of the deletion process to delete all of the things you've posted, like your photos, status updates or other data stored in backup systems. While Facebook deleting this information, it is inaccessible to other people using Facebook.